# Is it possible to inject an interface into Laravels Kernel.php?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5, repository-pattern

I am currently refactoring my Laravel 5 project in order to make use of the [Repository Design Pattern](http://heera.it/laravel-repository-pattern#.V1GtWfl97IV).

I have a created repository interface and a repository class:

```
interface UserRepositoryInterface {
    [...]
}

class UserRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface
{
   [...]
}
```

then added the necessary binding in the service provider class:

```
App::bind('App\Repositories\UserRepositoryInterface','App\Repositories\UserRepository');
```

and the injected the interface into the controller constructor:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(UserRepositoryInterface $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }
}
```

This part works fine. The problem is that I need to use some of the repository methods in the **app\Console\Kernel.php** class, where I implemented some scheduled tasks. I tried injecting the Kernel constructor in a similar fashion:

```
/**
 * Create a new console kernel instance.
 */
public function __construct(Application $app, Dispatcher $events, UserRepositoryInterface $userRepository)
{
    parent::__construct($app, $events);

    $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
}
```

However, this approach does not work (e.g. running 'php artisan tinker' in the Terminal fails). I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target
>   [App\Repositories\UserRepositoryInterface] is not instantiable while
>   building [App\Console\Kernel]. in D:\xampp\htdocs\budget-and-expe
>   nse-management\local\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:752
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 D:\xampp\htdocs\budget-and-expense-management\local\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(633):
>
> Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\Repositorie...', Array)
>
> ## 1 D:\xampp\htdocs\budget-and-expense-management\local\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(697):
>
> Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\Repositorie...', Array)
>
> ## 2 D:\xampp\htdocs\budget-and-expense-management\local\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(853):
>
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\Repositorie...')
>
> ## 3 D:\xampp\htdocs\budget-and-expense-management\local\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(808):
>
> Illuminate\C in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\budget-and-expense-management\local\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illum
>   inate\Container\Container.php on line 752
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target
>   [App\Repositories\UserRepositoryInterface] is not instantiable while
>   building [App\Console\Kernel]. in D:\xampp\htdocs\budget-and-expense-m
>   anagement\local\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
>   on line 752
>
> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target
>   [App\Repositories\UserRepositoryInterface] is not instantiable while
>   building [App\Console\Kernel]. in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\budget-and-expense-management\local\vendor
>   \laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 752
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0006     345568   1. {main}() D:\xampp\htdocs\budget-and-expense-management\local\artisan:0
>       0.0365    1417504   2. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make() D:\xampp\htdocs\budget-and-expense-management\local\artisan:31
>       0.0365    1417552   3. Illuminate\Container\Container->make() D:\xampp\htdocs\budget-and-expense-management\local\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:697
>       0.0367    1417552   4. Illuminate\Container\Container->build() D:\xampp\htdocs\budget-and-expense-management\local\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:633
>       0.0367    1417552   5. Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container{closure}()
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\budget-and-expense-management\local\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:735
>       0.0367    1417576   6. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make() D:\xampp\htdocs\budget-and-expense-management\local\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:230
>       0.0367    1417576   7. Illuminate\Container\Container->make() D:\xampp\htdocs\budget-and-expense-management\local\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:697
>       0.0368    1417576   8. Illuminate\Container\Container->build() D:\xampp\htdocs\budget-and-expense-management\local\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:633
>       0.0388    1453584   9. Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependencies()
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\budget-and-expense-management\local\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:777
>       0.0397    1456432  10. Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass()
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\budget-and-expense-management\local\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:808

I would like to know if it is at all possible to inject a repository interface into the Kernel, and, if yes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible, but `$userRepository = \App::make('App\Repositories\UserRepositoryInterface')` should work fine and basically has the same result (though DI is probably cleaner and easier to test, but who tests the Kernel anyway?)

Answer (score 7):

You are doing it wrong. I suppose you wrote your scheduled tasks directly in the Kernel in closures. Instead, wrap your commands logic in [Console commands](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan)

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class MyCoolCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'mycool:command';

    protected $repository = null;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $repository)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // your logic here
    }

}
```

and then call them in the kernel like this:

```
$schedule->command('mycool:command')->daily();
```

You can then define each command dependencies separately in the command constructor, clean up your kernel and write some testable and pretty code :)

Comment: The difference though in this answer and the original question, is that here you are not using dependency injection. You're referencing the repository directly. I'm having this same issue and what I'd like to do is use UserRepositoryInterface here in the Command file, and have that automatically bound to the repository, just like I can do in a controller. Is this possible?